# Python equivalent of Java Timer java.util.Timer

Tags: java, python, timer, scheduler

Java SE has a scalable [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) object that, using one single thread, allows large numbers of concurrently scheduled tasks (thousands should present no problem). It internally uses a binary heap to represent its task queue.

Is there a Python equivalent? Standard or in a very popular library is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, have a look at the [sched](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module. It utilizes binary heap (from [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)) as well.